# How do I use iptables with bridge-utils to block a MAC address?

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I have a server with `eth0` and `eth1`. To create a bridge I installed `bridge-utils`:

```
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils -y
```

And edited the `/etc/network/interfaces` with `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports eth0 eth1
```

And all works! The following works for blocking a MAC address:

```
sudo ebtables -A FORWARD -s 20:cf:30:3e:68:2a -j DROP
```

But not with `iptables`:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-source 20:cf:30:3e:68:2a -j DROP
```

It doesn't work, but  I prefer to do it with `iptables` because I need the `--timestart` option and that is only available in `iptables`.

Thanks

Comment: Use `-t nat PREROUTING` instead `FORWARD` chain. To not copy paste - please see the section 9 http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section8